# WiFi Controller system for a motor Relay Output

Tags: motor, dc

I'm trying to use a 12 volt WiFi relay setup to control a 12 volt DC motor. The WiFi relay has eight 10 A SPDT relays in it and the motor is 15 A. I understand how to wire it directly to the two relays that are in the box, but I'm lost after that. Here are my questions:

Since I'm using two 10 A relays at the same time to control the motor (positive through one and ground through the other), does this mean that I have a 20 A capacity with the relays?

How else could I wire this up to increase the relay capacity (or run the signals from the WiFi relays) to other relays and protect the WiFi relay box?

Here's the info on [the WiFi relay:](http://www.ourautomation.com/mobile-phone-smartphone-wifi-controller-for-android-or-ios-%E2%80%93-8-channel-relay-output-p-1579.html)

Answer (score 1):

No wiring the motor's positive line through one relay and the motor's negative line through another relay will NOT give you a 20A current capability.
Then the 15A of the motor still has to pass twice through a relay rated for 10 A.

If and only IF you are able to open and close 2 relay SIMULTANEOUSLY then it might work if you connect the relays in parallel. And then still I would not recommend that. It looks like the control application does not even allow you to
switch two relay simultaneously anyway.

But please have a look at the relay themselves, it is possible that they are rated for 10A at 240V, sometimes these relays can handle a larger current at a lower voltage. So you might be lucky since your motor runs at 12 V.

In case 10 A is really the limit of the relays, you will need a relay that can handle the 15A of the motor. Then you switch on/off that relay with the Wifi relay box. If the new relay works on 12 V you can use the 12 V power supply for the motor to power it. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSzaOt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'd suggest an automotive relay for `RLY1` - high current @ 12V and (typically) a protection diode built-in across the coil to save fusing the contacts on `RLY2`.